# Swiftmailer weird error

Tags: symfony, swiftmailer

I get this weird error when FOSUserBundle try to send an email to retrieve a password:

Warning: preg_match(): Compilation failed: internal error: previously-checked referenced subpattern not found at offset 4246 in /opt/lampp/htdocs/project/vendor/swiftmailer/lib/classes/Swift/Mime/Headers/MailboxHeader.php line 308

Someone knows what is it ? I've no idea !

Answer (score 0):

Seems like a edge case error as described here: https://groups.google.com/forum/?fromgroups=#!topic/swiftmailer/tgsOQstpKYo